# How to add a username to group www on Linux

Tags: linux, ftp

I'm following this [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052875/setting-up-ftp-on-amazon-cloud-server) to install FTP on my Linux EC2 server.

Managed to complete everything, except adding my FTP user to the group "www" as per:

```
sudo usermod -a -G www <USERNAME>
```

When I do this I get the error:

```
usermod: group 'www' does not exist
```

I'm having trouble finding how to add this group "www".

Comment: If the group doesn't exist, what do you think you should do next?

Comment: Yes, but how do I add a group?

Comment: What has your research revealed on that topic?

Comment: A lot of instructions on adding users to a group, but not how the group gets on the system in the first place.

Comment: "In this specific example, it's typical to give the user permissions to the 'www' group, which is often associated with the /var/www folder", does that folder exist, what security on it ?

Comment: Yes that is the folder I'm trying to assign ownership to (/var/www). It is currently owned by root.root

Comment: @DanielWilliams - there are default groups created when the OS is first installed, and then there are those that are added by installers like apache which often add the user www-data.  If you want your web server to be able to read the group as well it also needs to belong to that group.  Maybe you should pick up a linux basics book.  This is one of the most basic of all things unix-like.

Comment: Yes, I am no expert, but I am trying. If I try and change group to www-data I get `chgrp: invalid group: ‘www-data’`

Comment: Well, sorry, but the tutorial from 4 year ago is just broke.

Comment: Check the man pages.  man addgroup", "man chmod".  If you haven't installed apache before then www-data may not exist.  It's created by the installer scripts.

Comment: All I needed was someone to tell me `groupadd www` instead of giving me all this grief about being a n00b.

Comment: @DanielWilliams Why we didn't told you that ? If you create a new group, that mean that folder or anything around are not using it. That's why Matt was talking about www-data. we tried to see what and where you wanted to give permission..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`groupadd`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/groupadd) to create your group first.